# Deletion GC ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist, garbage-collection

I have some questions regarding removal of objects from an arrayList, as you can see below, I create a JComponent, add it to an arrayList, and add it to the JPanel, afterwards I remove it from the Arraylist, but it's still stuck to the JPanel ?
Why is the object still added to the Jpanel ? Referenced by the "add" method ?
Should I jp.remove(obj), to remove completly? If not, how do I remove it completly? <- main question.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Frame extends JFrame{
public Frame(){
    Jpanel jp = new Jpanel();
    getContentPane().add(jp);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
}

public class Jpanel extends JPanel{

    public Jpanel(){
        ArrayList<Obj> ArrList = new ArrayList<Obj>();
        setLayout(null);
        Obj obj = new Obj();
        ArrList.add(obj);
        add(obj);
        ArrList.remove(0);
        System.out.println(ArrList);
        revalidate();
        repaint();

    }
}

public class Obj extends JComponent{
    public Obj(){
        setBounds(0,0, 100 , 100);
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
Frame f = new Frame();
}
```

}

Comment: Why would you *expect* removing it from the list to remove it from the panel?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thought it would remove the reference to it, and GC then would delete it.

Comment: No, you've asked it to remove it from the list - so that's all it will remove it from. It would be *very* odd if you couldn't remove an element from a collection without it affecting other things.

Comment: And the object is still in scope of the constructor, so the GC couldn't delete it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ArrayList has nothing whatever to do with what is being painted on the screen. After you have called `add(obj)`, the object is in the JPanel until you call `remove(obj)`.

Comment: so to remove it COMPLETLY, I only need to remove from arrList and the Jpanel ? Then garbage Collector takes care of the rest`?

Comment: @JesperTuborgMadsen if there are more references to it earlier(when making it or preparing it for example) you need to delete those as well.

Comment: @Jesper The garbage collector does not affect your program in any way. Assuming you had sufficent RAM you could run a program with the GC turned off and the program would run exactly the same. The GC's only job is to free memory that your progrsm is no longer using. You as the programmer should never need to worry about what the GC is doing.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the object still added to the Jpanel ?

By method `ArrList.remove(0)` you are actually removing a reference to that object from `ArrayList` **NOT** the object referenced by `obj` itself. The object still remain there on heap. It is different thing that the object will be garbage collected if it is not reachable by strong reference. But the object is not garbage collected because `JPanel` is still referencing that object.

> Should I jp.remove(obj), to remove completly?

By doing this you remove the object from `JPanel` and make the object eligible for garbage collection , but you can't remove the object explicitly from heap memory.It is only the JVM which decides that when an object will be  garbage collected .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as there is a reference to the object on some non-daemon thread, the object will persist.

Adding an object to an ArrayList just gives the ArrayList a reference to your object. When you remove the object, the ArrayList forgets that reference. The object that was referenced will only be deleted when everything forgets the object.

To remove it completely, you must eradicated all references to it or things that may reference it. Then, the garbage collector will delete its data when it thinks it needs the memory.